# Trying to pass ragged array to library qsort function

Tags: c, qsort

Is there any way to do this with a ragged array?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
/*function for use in built-in quick sort*/
static int compare(const void *x,const void *y){
    return strcmp(*(const char**)x, *(const char**)y);
}

int main(){
    FILE *p = fopen("file.txt","w");
    char ch = '\0',**c = (char**)calloc(6,sizeof(char*));
    int n[6]={0},i=0,j=0;
    fprintf(p,"jack\ndanny\njohn\nrachael\nrobin\ntom");
    fclose(p);
    p = fopen("file.txt","r");
    while(1){/*count number of char to create ragged array*/
        while((ch=getc(p))!= '\n'){
            if(ch == EOF) break;
            putchar(ch);
            n[i]++;
        }
        printf(" %d\n",n[i]);
        if(ch == EOF) break;
        ch = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    ch = '\0';
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)/*allocating memory*/
        c[i] = (char*) calloc(n[i],sizeof(char));
    fclose(p);
    i=0;
    p = fopen("file.txt","r");
    while(1){/*read from file to ragged array*/
        while((ch=getc(p))!= '\n'){
            if(ch == EOF) break;
            *(c[i]+j) = ch;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        j = 0;
        if(ch == EOF) break;
        ch = '\0';
    }
    /*using built-in quick sort*/
    qsort(*c,6,sizeof(char*),compare);/*why won't this work?*/

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf("%s\n",*c[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked with array of strings declared in the main itself but failed when I used a ragged array to get the input from a file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works after editing this part,                                     for(i=0;i<6;i++)
            printf("%s\n",c[i]);

Comment: Sorry sorry I got it :)

Comment: It only works by chance. If you run your program through e.g. valgrind, it will detect numerous buffer overflows.

Comment: I've heard of jagged arrays, but "ragged" arrays?

Comment: Note: `printf("%s\n",*c[i]);` uses the first _character_ of each string and prints it as a string. `qsort(*c ...` does it wrong the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)/*allocating memory*/
        c[i] = (char*) calloc(n[i],sizeof(char));
```

You need to account for the nul terminator after each string too, this should be

```
        c[i] = (char*) calloc(n[i] + 1,sizeof(char));
```

Keep in mind that when you read the strings back, you need to ensure they are nul
terminated too. It's not needed now, since calloc() will ensure the last byte in your
string is the value 0, but generally something to be aware of.

```
    /*using built-in quick sort*/
    qsort(*c,6,sizeof(char*),compare);/*why won't this work?*/
```

Dereferencing c and passing it to qsort will just be wrong, it should be just

```
    qsort(c,6,sizeof(char*),compare);
```

Same thing with the printf , *c[i] is not a char * as the printf %s formatter will expect. It should be

```
        printf("%s\n",c[i]);
```